# Is there a way to add a new field in django models that is calculated on the basis of other 2 fields in the same model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    kt = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.FloatField()
```

I have this model, now I want to add a field to this model that is calculated with this formula:
`kt_21 = kt/21*quantity`
so I want a new field (kt_21) that is calculated by dividing the 2 already existing fields

I could not find any solution to this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add an extra field. Probably it is better to calculate it on demand, so as a property:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    kt = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.FloatField()

    @property
    def kt_21(self):
        return self.kt / 21 * self.quantity
```

for an `Issue` object `my_issue`, you can then determine it with `self.kt_21`.

Comment: thanks, but I need to show it in the table and add it to the database

Comment: Figured it out, thanks to you

Comment: @user17785103: it would be bad code design to add it to the table, since it can be completely derived from other columns, and thus would be *data uplication*.

Comment: @user17785103: it would imply updating the extra column for each insert and update. But it turns out that is quite complicated, especially since Django's `.save()` method does *not* run if you update the queryset in bulk. It would thus introduce all sorts of scenario's where the extra column shows inconsistent data.

Comment: The main concern was to present the kt_21 amount to the user, as you said I achieved ut through making it a property and then rendering it to the template as a context